# Charge a conditional Delivery fee in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

This is my condition like:

> If subtotal <= certain amount && subtotal <= certain amount

So if the subtotal matches this criteria then I want to charge a delivery fee which should also show in the email invoice.

Currently this is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','my_delivery_fee' );
function my_delivery_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
    if(subtotal <= certain amount && subtotal <= certain amount){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Delivery Fees', 5, true, 'standard' );
    } 

}
```

But it is not showing any thing.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your condition. it should be instead:

> If subtotal <= amount && **subtotal > amount2**

Also your code is a bit old, try it this way (an example of progressive fee):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','my_delivery_fee', 10, 1 );
function my_delivery_fee( $wc_cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $subtotal = $wc_cart->subtotal;
    $fee = 0;

    // Progressive fee
    if(subtotal < 25 ){ // less than 25 
        $fee = 5;
    } elseif( subtotal >= 25 && subtotal < 50){ // between 25 and 50
        $fee = 10;
    } else { // From 50 and up 
        $fee = 15;
    }

    if( fee > 0 )
        $wc_cart->add_fee( 'Delivery Fees', $fee, true, 'standard' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Loic i read you answer every time really you are doing the great code can you guide me to increase my coding knowledge?